# Django form: Form is validated but does not populate database

Tags: python, django

I am banging my head on the wall for a while now and can't find out the key to the error I must be making.

I have a modelform in templates that does not output any error, it redirects normally so I am assuming that the form gets valided, but nothing makes it through the database. I reviewed a ton of posts about similar issues here but nothing seem to solve my problem.
Here is what my code look like:

models.py

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    SaleID = models.AutoField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    SaleProductName= models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='products_catalogue', on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank=True, null=True)
    SalePartnersName = models.ForeignKey(Partners, related_name='partner_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)   
    SalePartnerBusinessName = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="NA")
    SaleQuantity = models.FloatField(max_length=100,default="NA")
    SaleUnit = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="NA")
    SaleNetAmount = models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    SalesBroker = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Not Involved")
    SalePartnerCommission = models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    SaleDate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    SaleStatus = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Ongoing")
```

views.py

```
def RecordNewDealView(request):
     
     if request.method == 'POST':
          form = RecordNewDealForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
          return redirect('my_deals.html') 
     else:
          form = RecordNewDealForm()
          context = {'form': form,}
            
          return render(request, 'record_new_deal.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class RecordNewDealForm(forms.ModelForm):
       
       SaleID = forms.CharField(label='Sale ID')                       
       SaleStatus = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=SALE_STATUS_CHOICES), label='Status')
       SalesBroker = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES_OF_BROKERS), label='Broker')
       SaleProductName = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Products.objects.all(),label='Product Name')
       SalePartnersName = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Partners.objects.all(), label='Contact')
       SaleUnit = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICE_OF_UNITS), label='Unit')
       SalePartnerBusinessName = forms.CharField(label='Customer Name')
       SaleQuantity = forms.FloatField(label='Quantity') 
       SaleNetAmount = forms.FloatField(label='Net Amount') 
       SaleDate = forms.CharField(label="Date Created")
       SalePartnerCommission = forms.CharField(label="Commission") 
        
            
            
       class Meta:
            model = Sales
            fields = ("SaleID",
                      "SaleProductName",
                      "SalePartnerBusinessName",
                      "SaleQuantity",
                      "SaleUnit","SaleNetAmount",
                      "SalePartnerCommission", "SaleDate"
                      ,"SalesBroker","SalePartnersName","SaleStatus"
                     
                     )
```

and finally, here is my template:

```
 <form method="POST">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
             
             {% csrf_token %} 
             {{ form.non_field_errors }}
             <h2> Start a New Deal </h2>
             <hr align="left" style="width:40%">
            </div>
           
            <br>
           
            
           </div>
 
            
          
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-2">
    
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
           {{ form.SaleDate.errors }}
           {{ form.SaleDate|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
             <div class="fieldWrapper">
           {{ form.SaleStatus.errors }}
           {{ form.SaleStatus |as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
            
            
            <div class="col-sm-9">
             <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead class="thead">
                  <tr>
                   <th scope="col"><a href='/my_deals_details'>PRODUCT DETAILS</a></th>
                   <th scope="col"><a href='/my_deals_details'>CUSTOMER DETAILS</a></th>
                   <th scope="col"><a href='/my_deal_broker'>BROKER DETAILS</a></th>
 
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="background-color: white">
                 
                    {% csrf_token %} 
                   {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                    <tr>
                
                     <td>  
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <div class="fieldWrapper">
          {{ form.SaleProductName.errors }}
          {{ form.SaleProductName |as_crispy_field }}
           
          {{ form.SaleQuantity.errors }}
          {{ form.SaleQuantity |as_crispy_field }}
                       
           {{ form.SaleUnit.errors }}
          {{ form.SaleUnit |as_crispy_field }}
           
        {{ form.SaleNetAmount.errors }}
          {{ form.SaleNetAmount |as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
                      </div>
            </td>
                     <td>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <div class="fieldWrapper">
                        
         {{ form.SalePartnersName.errors }}
          {{ form.SalePartnersName|as_crispy_field  }}
                        </div>
        
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
              {{ form.SalePartnerBusinessName.errors }}
             
          {{ form.SalePartnerBusinessName|as_crispy_field }}
             
            </div>
                      </div>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <div class="fieldWrapper">
           {{ form.SalesBroker.errors }}
          {{ form.SalesBroker |as_crispy_field }}
           
          {{ form.SalePartnerCommission.errors }}
          {{ form.SalePartnerCommission |as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
                      </div>
 
                     </td>
                     </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>  
             
             
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
                   
                   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/my_deals.html">Cancel</a>
              </form>
```

Sorry for dumping quite a lot of code here. I can't seem to see the elephant in the room! I have verified everything, including every div tag in my templates and can't seem to find out the issue. Maybe a pair of fresh eyes could help me unblock the situation. Thank you!

Comment: You are ***NOT*** accounting for when the form validation fails. You're redirecting to `my_deals.html` even when the form validation fails. For instance, the `if form.is_valid()` line should have a matching `else` that should contain something like `render(request, 'record_new_deal.html', {'form': form})`. That will show you what's wrong with the form.

Comment: thanks for your response, I appreciate. Would you be able to show me how it would look like? I am a bit confused because it is not what the documentation seems to explain about passing forms and validating them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing any errors is because you are not rendering the form back to the end users when the form validation fails. The following is your view function that's been updated to render the form back to the end users whenever the validation fails:

```
def RecordNewDealView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RecordNewDealForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Since the form has been successfully validated, we can
            # save the associated model and redirect
            form.save()
            return redirect('my_deals.html')
        # if this is reached, that means that the form validation failed.
        # So, we should render the template with the errors
        return render(request, 'record_new_deal.html', {'form': form})
    form = RecordNewDealForm()
    context = {'form': form,}
    return render(request, 'record_new_deal.html', context)
```

As mentioned in the comments, when `form.is_valid()` is `False`, then the `record_new_deal.html` is rendered, along with the form and all the associated errors.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Abdou's suggestion, you probably want to edit `RecordNewDealView` to look like the following. If the form is not valid, it will contain the errors and be rendered with errors in `record_new_deal.html`:

```
def RecordNewDealView(request):
     
     if request.method == 'POST':
          form = RecordNewDealForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               return redirect('my_deals.html') 
     else:
         form = RecordNewDealForm()
     context = {'form': form,}
            
     return render(request, 'record_new_deal.html', context)
```